# What ever happend to the d3j.s force directed graph cluster example see on this image?

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

What ever happend to the d3.js example on this image.

The force directed graph cluster.  Second row, 3rd column?

http://vis.stanford.edu/papers/d3

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are interested in is the shapes surrounding groups of nodes.

The following examples implement it :

- [force-multi-foci with convex hulls](http://bl.ocks.org/donaldh/2920551)
- [alpha-shapes aka concave hulls in d3](http://bl.ocks.org/gka/1552725)

Hope this helps,